# Eclipse setup for Hadoop development

Tags: hadoop, windows-7-x64, eclipse-indigo

I am using  hadoop 1.0.3 version .
I tried configuring hadoop Eclipse Indigo.
But It failed to start dfs and showed error failed to login.[image]

plz suggest me what is the problem in map/reduce?

**edit :** I am using windows 7 so firstly install **cygwin** than **hadoop1.0.4** and started service on
`http://127.0.0.1:50030/ and http://localhost:50070/` successfully.

Comment: You should check your mapred and dfs ports, did you do that?

Comment: yes, port are localhost:9100 and localhost:9101.

Comment: Did you use that ports on your hadoop plugin configuration?

Comment: yes, i am using 9100 in cross-site.xml and 9101 in mapred-site.xml

Answer (score 0):

Check if you install hadoop properly. Try to install hadoop plugin, as you can see in [install plugin](http://v-lad.org/Tutorials/Hadoop/13.5%20-%20copy%20hadoop%20plugin.html). You can see a tutorial for this in [haddop video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2SU4qZwz8HU). Also, take a look to [eclipse setup for hadoop development](http://orzota.com/blog/eclipse-setup-for-hadoop-development/).

Comment: yes i edit my question..i am successfully installed hadoop and started services and i m also following the same link.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Indigo is version 3.7. You can read "Any eclipse before 3.6 is compatible to the eclipse plugin. (Doesn't work with Eclipse 3.7)" http://www.orzota.com/eclipse-setup-for-hadoop-development/